# Is it possible to create inner hyper reference in Latex file ?

Tags: cross-referencing

I'd like to create a link that once it is clicked will take to a specific line or marked point in a defined place. For example, in page one I want to reference a line 5 in page 12.

Is it possible to create something like this?

Comment: Will the target change with the text (so, more text before line 5 might push the target down to line 6 or 7, say), or will the target always be one line 5 of page 12?

Comment: I got your point, I think it will change based on what I'm writing in the page earlier. is it possible just to define a marker in line 5 page 12 and use this point as a reference doesn't matter where this point is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this `hypperef` useage is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-10]

Some text that will occupie one line and go at least to the second. On this second line will me a label that the ref command will point at. Here it is \phantomsection\label{test}{{\color{red}HERE}}

\lipsum[1-10]

Here is the link: \hyperref[test]{Text for the link}

\end{document}
```

No screenshot because you have to click to check results